# Javascript method setTimeout() does not work well in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, safari, mobile-safari

I try to develop javascript codes that can give users a warning when the server too long to response the html form submitted. My codes works well in Chrome and Firefox desktop browser, but not in Safari desktop browser. 
How to make this works in Safari ? Here are my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleTimeout() {
         document.getElementById("retryButton").disabled = false;
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Your card's bank 3DS OTP page might be having issue. Please \"Tap to retry\".";
      }
      function retry() {
         setTimeout(handleTimeout, 5000);
         submitForm();
      }
      function submitForm() {
         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            document.getElementById('requestForm').submit();
            resolve("done");
         });
      }
      function start() {
         document.getElementById("retryButton").disabled = true;
         setTimeout(handleTimeout, 5000);
         submitForm();
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
         start();
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="requestForm" method="post" action="http://localhost:10877/auth/pareq">
   <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4wLjIiLC"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="uuid" value="ac456037-995b-4778-bba5-df614db7ebaa"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="Status" value="Y"/>
</form>
<div id="message">Processing OTP</div>
<p>Tap the button below to Retry</p><br/>
<button id="retryButton" onclick="retry();">Tap to retry</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Function `handleTimeout()` is not working in Safari but works well in Chrome and Firefox browser. 
How to make function `handleTimeout()` works well in Safari?

Comment: @Bravo function `handleTimeout()` called in Safari, but it fails, no message "Your card's bank 3DS OTP page might be having issue. Please \"Tap to retry\"." shown.

Comment: so the function doesn't get called? or is there perhaps an error in the browser console? put a console log as the first line of that function to see if it's being called

Comment: which version of safari?

Comment: @Bravo the function is called, i've put the console log, no error in the console. But the message is not updated. The display of Safari browser seems stuck after submitting the form.

Comment: @Bravo Safari Desktop browser version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8)

Comment: oh, probably because the form is submitted, the page reloads - not sure how it can possibly work in any browser in that case, since a form submit causes a new page to be loaded - i.e. page `http://localhost:10877/auth/pareq`

Comment: @Bravo trust me this works well in Chrome and Firefox, I've tried it many times.

Comment: Perhaps failed form submission works different in Safari - everything else in Safari works differently, it's the new Internet Explorer